# Specifying a login table

Tags: python, django

I have a login form. The problem is that it uses data from default table created by django called `auth_user`. I created a data model and it is in the database. How can I make my login form to get data from this table and not the default table?

**signin.html:**

```
<form action="\polls\auth" method="post">
  <div class="form-group mb10">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group nomargin">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><a href="" class="forgot">Forgot password?</a></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-quirk btn-block">Sign In</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**model.py:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
#from django.forms import ModelForm

class Registration(models.Model):
    #class Meta:
        #model=Registration
    userName= models.CharField(max_length=100, default="username")
    password = models.CharField( max_length=100, default="password")
    fullName= models.CharField( max_length=100, default="my name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userName
```

**myview.py:**

```
def auth_view(request): ## this view is for login
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/index')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/signin', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

any hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [substitute custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: By customising I have to code my own authentication.right?Is it not another big task?should I just use the available authentication?I just use the django login and registration form?

Comment: Please read the documentation - link provided in my previous comment. Generally substituting the default user model (table) is quite an advanced and complicated topic.